# Why Wolfram 12.1 not calculated?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, functions, numerics

Why doesn't scientific software count,

```
In[1]:= h = 6.2607015*10^(-34)
c = 299792458
w = 2153.96
k = 1.380649*10^(-23)
t = 296
Q = 1/(1 - Exp[-h*c*w/k*t])

Out[1]= 6.2607*10^-34

Out[2]= 299792458

Out[3]= 2153.96

Out[4]= 1.38065*10^-23

Out[5]= 296

During evaluation of In[1]:= General::munfl: Exp[-8667.42] is too small to represent as a normalized machine number; precision may be lost.

Out[6]= 1.
```

but bullshit excel does?

[image]

Please, explain me

Comment: It looks like you're missing a set of parenthesis around the denominator of the argument to Exp. It looks like you entered it correctly in Excel. See the two comments I added to the answer below for more details.  @Nasser

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your excel result makes no sense. First, you have $k=0$, but this should have produced division by zero as you have term `-h*c*w/k*t`. I have no idea how Excel gave 10.6 as a result. (does excel detect division by zero?)

Mathematica's result is correct. If you want the exact value without the **"Exp[-8667.42] is too small to represent as a normalized machine
number; precision may be lost"**  , here it is

```
h = SetAccuracy[6.2607015*10^(-34), Infinity]
c = 299792458
w = 215396/100
k = SetAccuracy[1.380649*10^(-23), Infinity]
t = 296
Q = 1/(1 - Exp[-h*c*w/k*t])
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Lets see if Excel can do the above.

If you set `k = 0;` then the result will be

```
Power::infy: Infinite expression 1/0 encountered.
```

Comment: It looks as though Excel is displaying both of the two small numbers input in scientific notation as 0's (h and k - h is being input at the top, but shows up as 0.0000). This may be caused by the formatting chosen in Excel. It looks like the denominator is missing a set of parenthesis.The k is Boltzmann's constant, and it normally multiplies the temperature T, so the denominator should be /(k*t) or /k/t, instead of k*t. This adjusts the expression inside Exp by a factor 300^2. If I evaluate the inputs the OP supplied with this correction, Mathematica returns 10.6169 for machine ...

Comment: ..precision. Increasing the precision (instead of accuracy) to 150 for all non-integer terms gives essentially the same result, so the Excel version must've had the correct term in the denominator.

Comment: Oh, thank you. Setting the accuracy helped.
And yes there should be another bracket